# UIButton bring to front of scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, autocomplete, uibutton

I m running into a large problem. I have a `textfield` for which Im doing autocomplete feature to display a list of items when tappe inside. I display the items in `tableView`(autocomplete tableView). I have a `UIbutton` below `textfield`. Now when I select an item from autocomplete textfield and click on the button it is not responding.
I dont know why.

I have brought it front in `didendediting` and also in `didSelectrow` but of no use.I have added a `UIbutton` to `ScrollView`(testScroll)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
           Name.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
           [Name resignFirstResponder];
           [testScroll bringSubviewToFront:btnSearch];
           autocompleteTableView.hidden=true;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 if(textField==CompanyName)
    {

        [testScroll bringSubviewToFront:btnSearch];

}
```

}

Where I m going wrong ?

EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {



    if(textField==Name)
    {

        autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

        NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
        substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
        return YES;
        if([Name.text length]==0)
        {
            autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;

        }
    }



}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];
        [parser release];



        if([arr4 count]!=0)
        {
            self.autocompleteUrls = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
            viewForautoCompleteTableView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 370, 295, 230)];



            if(autocompleteTableView)
                [autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];

            autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,295,150) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
            autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
            autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
            autocompleteTableView.rowHeight=28;

            autocompleteTableView.backgroundView = nil;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            autocompleteTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            [autocompleteTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            [viewForautoCompleteTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(220,370 ,295,autocompleteTableView.frame.size.height)];


            [viewForautoCompleteTableView addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
            [self.view addSubview:viewForautoCompleteTableView];

            [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
            for(int i=0;i<[arr4 count];i++)
            {
             NSString *curString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[arr4 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"],[[arr4 objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LastName"]];

                [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];

            }




        }
        [autocompleteTableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Whay are you using scroll with table view ...any ways change the color of all views to green red blue whatever and then run your app u will get fair idea

Comment: Hi @arizah, paste your autocomplete tableview code. May be after selected value is displaying in textfield, tableview doesn't disappear completely and hiding the button below it. please check.

Comment: chck if button id touchable

Comment: I have edited my code and posted the part of autocomplete tableView.Can u please have a look and let me know.

Comment: I have given varoius colours and checked it but of no use.And the button is also touchable bcoz when I move it some other part it is clickable.Only when tableview appears I couldnot click it ..

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti please review my code and let me know..

Comment: @arizah, have you tried with the below code?

Comment: Yes I tried just now and still im not getting button clickable.I dont know y ?Is my didfinishloading code correct?Please find a solution

Comment: @arizah, Could you please set border color to tableview and verify whether button is below the tableview.  ignore ([substring characterAtIndex:0] == 10).

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti I have set redcolour and checked .And button is below tableview only.Still I m not getting

Comment: @arizah, below means: is the tableview suppressing button? if not, please check button id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25266/discussion-between-arizah-and-ramu-pasupuleti)

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti  Yes tableView is supressing button .i.e button is getting hidden below tableview.After selecting a cell tableview is hidden and I could see the button but I could not click it.It is not clickable

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti did u check my comment...

Comment: @arizah, put autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES; in textFieldDidEndEditing also. Lets continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: yes im there in chat .but I couldn't see messages im sending .just a min

Answer (score 2):

I had experienced same problem and fixed with the help of below code.

Edit below two functions as below:

```
in .h:

 int isValueSelected;
```

in .m:

In viewDidLoad:
isValueSelected =0;

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        if (isValueSelected == 1)
        {
            autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
            isValueSelected = 0;
        }else{
            NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
            substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
            if((substring.length ==0) || ([substring characterAtIndex:0] == 10) || (autocompleteUrls.count == 0)){
                autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
            }else{
                autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
            }


        }

        return YES;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        urlField.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        isValueSelected = 1;
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;

    }
```

Comment: Yes I tried just now and still im not getting button clickable.I dont know y ?Is my didfinishloading code correct?Please find a solution

Comment: Can I know what is this ([substring characterAtIndex:0] == 10)?